# Use an SD card as internal storage

Tags: linux, kernel

I recently bought a Coowell V5 with a S905X mobo. I overwrote its firmware with one from a Nexbox A95 (that has the same S905X mobo), and now my internal partitions disappeared(mmcblk0p0,...p1,...).

What I think is, that either my internal memory is fried, or that my partitions just disappeared.

My question is, how can I remake them? Or maybe I can use an SD card and bind its partitions to the /system, /data, and /cache?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the app link2sd from here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=it

Comment: I can't because I can't boot into Android. I don't have any partitions.

Comment: Have you tried to hard reset o Flash the device?